# Convert Nested dictionary to Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Greetings to fellow programmer.

I have recently started with pyspark and comes from a pandas background. I need to compute similarity of user in a data against each other. As I couldn't find from pyspark I resorted to use python dictionary to create a similarity dataframe.

However, I run out of ideas to convert a nested dictionary into a pyspark Dataframe.
Could you please provide me a direction on to achieve this desired result.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from scipy.spatial import distance


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

from pyspark.sql import *

traindf = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('u11',[1, 2, 3]),
    ('u12',[4, 5, 6]),
    ('u13',[7, 8, 9])
]).toDF("user","rating")

traindf.show()
```

Output

```
+----+---------+
|user|   rating|
+----+---------+
| u11|[1, 2, 3]|
| u12|[4, 5, 6]|
| u13|[7, 8, 9]|
+----+---------+
```

It want to generate a similarity between user and put it in a pyspark dataframe.

```
parent_dict = {}
for parent_row in traindf.collect():
#     print(parent_row['user'],parent_row['rating'])
    child_dict = {}
    for child_row in traindf.collect():
        similarity = distance.cosine(parent_row['rating'],child_row['rating'])
        child_dict[child_row['user']] = similarity
    parent_dict[parent_row['user']] = child_dict

print(parent_dict)
```

Output :

```
{'u11': {'u11': 0.0, 'u12': 0.0253681538029239, 'u13': 0.0405880544333298},
 'u12': {'u11': 0.0253681538029239, 'u12': 0.0, 'u13': 0.001809107314273195},
 'u13': {'u11': 0.0405880544333298, 'u12': 0.001809107314273195, 'u13': 0.0}}
```

From this dictionary I want to construct a pyspark Dataframe.

```
+-----+-----+--------------------+
|user1|user2|          similarity|
+-----+-----+--------------------+
|  u11|  u11|                 0.0|
|  u11|  u12|  0.0253681538029239|
|  u11|  u13|  0.0405880544333298|
|  u12|  u11|  0.0253681538029239|
|  u12|  u12|                 0.0|
|  u12|  u13|0.001809107314273195|
|  u13|  u11|  0.0405880544333298|
|  u13|  u12|0.001809107314273195|
|  u13|  u13|                 0.0|
+-----+-----+--------------------+
```

What I have tried so far is convert dict to pandas dataframe and convert it to pyspark dataframe. However I need to do this on huge scale and I am looking for more spark-ish way of doing this.

```
parent_user = []
child_user = []
child_similarity = []

for parent_row in traindf.collect():
    
    for child_row in traindf.collect():
        similarity = distance.cosine(parent_row['rating'],child_row['rating'])
        child_user.append(child_row['user'])
        child_similarity.append(similarity)
        parent_user.append(parent_row['user'])

my_dict = {}
my_dict['user1'] = parent_user
my_dict['user2'] = child_user
my_dict['similarity'] = child_similarity

import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(my_dict))
df.show()
```

Output :

```
+-----+-----+--------------------+
|user1|user2|          similarity|
+-----+-----+--------------------+
|  u11|  u11|                 0.0|
|  u11|  u12|  0.0253681538029239|
|  u11|  u13|  0.0405880544333298|
|  u12|  u11|  0.0253681538029239|
|  u12|  u12|                 0.0|
|  u12|  u13|0.001809107314273195|
|  u13|  u11|  0.0405880544333298|
|  u13|  u12|0.001809107314273195|
|  u13|  u13|                 0.0|
+-----+-----+--------------------+
```

Comment: Do you know how to convert the dictionary to flat pandas dataframe? Then you can do it and then create pyspark dataframe. Or you can covert top-level dict  to list of key,dict, convert it to pyspark dataframe and then apply `explode` to the  dict column

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov I have tried that , I have update my question with that. However I am looking for more spark way of doing this. Please guide me on approach which could well scale for a million records. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

my_dic = {'u11': {'u11': 0.0, 'u12': 0.0253681538029239, 'u13': 0.0405880544333298},
                 'u12': {'u11': 0.0253681538029239, 'u12': 0.0, 'u13': 0.001809107314273195},
                 'u13': {'u11': 0.0405880544333298, 'u12': 0.001809107314273195, 'u13': 0.0}}

df =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dic).unstack().to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = ['user1', 'user2', 'similarity']
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc) # sc is spark context
sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df).show()
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Could you suggest some way which doesn't involve conversion to pandas dataframe.

Comment: @vedprakash you did a collect() on your Spark dataframe and bring  all data in your master node even if you manage to do this conversion using spark, I think your problem still there and your method doesn't scale well with more data

Comment: I suggest first re-desgin your method you did the things and then think about how convert your data to desired format.

Comment: I totally agree with your comments . How to re-design is where I am clueless about and essentially my approach is brute-force .

Comment: @vedprakash take a look at this: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Frank-Kanes-Taming-Big-Data-with-Apache-Spark-and-Python/blob/master/movie-similarities-cluster.py I think you want to do something like this, source code is very readable, and the MovieLens dataset publicly available

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now your question is more clear. I am assuming your are starting with a spark dataframe of user,rating.
What your want to do is outer join of this DF with itself, this will create a cross product  with all the possible pairs of the users (and their ratings), including lines of same user repeated twice (those can be filtered later) and then calculate new column that contains similarity.

Comment: yes you're absolutely right. I have written down this solution. This is working for me, however if it could be improved that will make me happy.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

def cos_sim(a,b):
    return float(np.dot(a, b) / (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b)))

dot_udf = psf.udf(lambda x,y: cos_sim(x,y), FloatType())

data.alias("i").join(data.alias("j"), psf.col("i.user") != psf.col("j.user"))\
    .select(
        psf.col("i.user").alias("user1"), 
        psf.col("j.user").alias("user2"), 
        dot_udf("i.rating", "j.rating").alias("similarity"))\
    .sort("similarity")\
    .show()
```

Output is as desired:

```
+-----+-----+----------+
|user1|user2|similarity|
+-----+-----+----------+
|  u11|  u12|0.70710677|
|  u13|  u11|0.70710677|
|  u11|  u13|0.70710677|
|  u12|  u11|0.70710677|
|  u12|  u13|       1.0|
|  u13|  u12|       1.0|
+-----+-----+----------+
```